# How to find all messages I ever written in public groups?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I used to post in a lot of public groups. I would like to delete all those posts now (don't want to delete account), however I don't exactly remember all the groups. How could I pull out all the posts associated with my account?

Comment: Have you tried to use the tool I recommended?

Answer (score 0):

You can look to [telegram-messages-dump](https://github.com/Kosat/telegram-messages-dump) library to get list of all messages in public group. And after just find suitable method for message deletion there.